# select() does not timeout after the interval specified in timeout structure

Tags: c, linux

I am trying out slightly modified version of the example provided in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/eventfd.2.html.

```
include <sys/eventfd.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <inttypes.h>           /* Definition of PRIu64 & PRIx64 */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>             /* Definition of uint64_t */

#define handle_error(msg) \
    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int efd;
    uint64_t u;
    ssize_t s;
    int j;
    int retval;
    fd_set rfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    int count = 0;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <num>...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    efd = eventfd(0, EFD_CLOEXEC | EFD_SEMAPHORE);
    if (efd == -1)
        handle_error("eventfd");

    switch (fork()) {
        case 0:
            for (j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
                printf("Child writing %s to efd\n", argv[j]);
                u = strtoull(argv[j], NULL, 0);
                /* strtoull() allows various bases */
                s = write(efd, &u, sizeof(uint64_t));
                if (s != sizeof(uint64_t))
                    handle_error("write");
            }
            printf("Child completed write loop\n");
            sleep(60);

            for (j = 1; j < argc; j++) {
                printf("Child writing %s to efd\n", argv[j]);
                u = strtoull(argv[j], NULL, 0);
                /* strtoull() allows various bases */
                s = write(efd, &u, sizeof(uint64_t));
                if (s != sizeof(uint64_t))
                        handle_error("write");
            }
            sleep(10);
            for (j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                printf("Child writing %s to efd\n", argv[j]);
                u = strtoull(argv[j], NULL, 0);
                /* strtoull() allows various bases */
                s = write(efd, &u, sizeof(uint64_t));
                if (s != sizeof(uint64_t))
                        handle_error("write");
            }

            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        default:
            FD_ZERO(&rfds);
            FD_SET(efd, &rfds);
            tv.tv_sec = 5;
            printf("Parent about to read\n");
            while(1) {
                count++;
                printf("entering\n");
                retval = select(efd + 1, &rfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
                printf("THE RETVAL IS %d\n", retval);
                if (retval == -1) {
                    printf("fetched nothing\n");
                }
                else if (retval > 0) {
                    s = read(efd, &u, sizeof(uint64_t));
                    if (s != sizeof(uint64_t))
                        handle_error("read");
                printf("Parent read %"PRIu64" (%#"PRIx64") from efd\n", u, u);
                }
                printf("count...%d\n", count);
        }
        case -1:
            handle_error("fork");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out 10 3 4 5
event fd is 3
Parent about to read
entering
Child writing 10 to efd
Child writing 3 to efd
Child writing 4 to efd
Child writing 5 to efd
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Child completed write loop
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...1
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...2
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...3
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...4
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...5
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...6
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...7
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...8
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...9
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...10
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...11
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...12
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...13
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...14
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...15
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...16
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...17
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...18
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...19
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...20
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...21
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...22
entering
Child writing 10 to efd
Child writing 3 to efd
Child writing 4 to efd
Child writing 5 to efd
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...23
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...24
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...25
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...26
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...27
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...28
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...29
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...30
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...31
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...32
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...33
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...34
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...35
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...36
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...37
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...38
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...39
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...40
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...41
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...42
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...43
entering
hey THE RETVAL IS 1
Parent read 1 (0x1) from efd
count...44
entering
.... upto 66
```

My objective is to basically monitor the event fd using `select()` from the parent process and then do a `read()` call. From the output, it seems that the parent process's select call is acting upon the fd only when the child process does some write operation. If the child process does not do anything i.e. if it sleeps then parent process kind of blocks the select call and it never times out even though 5 seconds have passed. Is there something more that I am missing here?

Comment: You forget to initialize the `tv_usec` member of the `tv` structure. Right now it will have an *indeterminate* value which could lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Is it mandatory to declare both? Also, `tv_usec` have to initialized to the same value in microseconds as seconds. right?

Comment: Yes you must initialize the whole structure. It can be initialized to zero, either explicitly (like you do with the `tv_sec` member), or by initializing the `tv` structure on definition (as in `struct timeval tv = { 0, 0 };`).

Comment: Initializing the `tv_usec` worked. Thank you. Can you add it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `tv_usec` member of the `tv` structure is not initialized, it will have an *indeterminate* value.

This indeterminate value could almost be seen as random or garbage, and could lead to undefined behavior.

And undefined behavior could manifest as it does in your case.

Even if you don't use the `tv_usec` field it needs to be initialized, preferably to `0` as it's not used.